# Manipulating which contact should be injected into a journey from SalesForce

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ssjs

Due to the business model, we have two groups of stakeholders to whom we need to communicate, clients and partners (refer clients to us but are not our customers themselves)

This division is also reflected in SalesForce where we have accounts belonging to clients as well as partner accounts which are interconnected with lookup fields. So in the account of Client A you can also find information (name, email, id, etc) concerning Partner B who referred the client to us.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to inject partner's Contact into a journey using SalesForce data as an entry source event whenever a certain event takes place in Clients Account. For example, a Client makes a large purchase so his referring partner should enter a journey and receive an email.

I know I can use SSJS via automation studio to modify information in the journey's data extension by looking up the data in synchronised data extensions but this means that the email can't be sent instantly as there may be up to an hour between contact entering the journey and SSJS activity running ?

I have also tried to modify the data relationship in Contact Builder to base it on partner's contactID which we added to clients account in Salesforce, but this didn't seem to solve the problem.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem by having two separate journeys running (one client and one partner) and using the client's journey to open a task on partner's account whenever the email needs to be sent. The partner journey's uses creation of this specific task as an entry event and then sends an email to a contact injected which in that case is obviously a partner.